# Python: ModuleNotFoundError even after successful pip installation

Tags: python, module, pip

I know a lot have been talked about this topic but I couldn't solve the problem.

I have only python 3.6.3 and pip 9 installed in my pc and I tried `pip install mudicom` and `pip3 install mudicom` on the command line. I also tried to cd into package's directory and run `py -3 setup.py install`.

When I write `pip list` on CMD, mudicom package appears in the list but when I try to import it on spyder IDE, I get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mudicom'" error.

Comment: what happens when you write `python -c "import mudicom" ` in a terminal?

Comment: @FlyingTeller it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdcm'. When I try to pip install gdcm it says the following: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gdcm (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gdcm

Comment: try restarting spyder.

Comment: @Megalng restarting didn't help either. I launch spyder using anaconda navigator.

Comment: Looks like you have not fullfilled all the dependencies for mudicom. Read this: https://github.com/neurosnap/mudicom/blob/master/docs/install.rst

Comment: @FlyingTeller thank you I am trying to install gdcm. However, I have the exact same problem with mritopng package. When I write `python -c "import mritopng"` in command line, it returns nothing. But I get the ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import mritopng on IDE too. Looks like there is something beyond dependencies.

Comment: If it works in command line then it should work in the IDE. The only issue here could be that the IDE is not set up correctly.

Comment: @FlyingTeller looks like python36/lib/site-packages directory wasn't in sys.path of spyder IDE. I appended it and problem solved, thank you very much.

Comment: That's an odd error. Is the Interpreter set to python36/bin/python ?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am sorry but what do you mean by that? How can I check  if it is or not?

Comment: Not that familiar with spyder, but somewhere in the settings you should be able to set the interpreter